# type for aliasing constexpr char[]

Tags: c++, reference, alias

Modified the question to make it clear. Sorry for my sloppy English wordings.

I am looking for a type of a variable, which is an alias of another variable of `constexpr char []` type. I've tried a few but none worked.

Here is an example:

```
constexpr char FieldX[] = "source";
WhatType OptY = FieldX;
```

The value of `FieldX` will not change at runtime -- obviously. However, later on, someone could change it in the source code and recompile. I would like to avoid having to change the value of `OptY` manually according to the change in the value of `FieldX`.

They have essentially same values; they are in different `.cc/.cpp` files, and would have better readability if the name of variables could be different.

Comment: Create a const or nonconst lvalue reference? That's why we call references as aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an alias of a variable, you want a *reference*.

```
constexpr char FieldX[] = "my_field_or_option";
constexpr auto& OptY = FieldX;

static_assert( sizeof FieldX == 19 );
static_assert( sizeof OptY == 19 );    // No array decay
```

Note that `FieldX` **must** be evaluated at compile time to be able to create a `constexpr` reference to it, meaning it should be global or `static`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cWKaKvYPa)

Comment: @JasonLiam hopefully my edit demonstrates that this code is valid C++ (and curbs the downvotes).

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, now with the note, it is fine.

Comment: Thank you! Instead of `auto&`, I think I tried a few different explicit types, which did not work. 

```
int x;
auto& ref = x;
```

Above, `ref` is of `int&` type. In your answer, what's the type of `OptY`? Thank you, again!

Comment: @Stephen `constexpr const char (&OptY)[19] = FieldX;`. Or just `constexpr const char *OptY = FieldX;`, if you don't need `sizeof` to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to have `OptY` as effectively `constexpr char[]`

With modern C++, you could use `decltype` as shown below:

```
constexpr char FieldX[] = "my_field_or_option";
using OptY = decltype(FieldX);     //create an alias
static_assert(sizeof(OptY) == 19);
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/snhcO8N_Mg)

If you want to alias variable then you can use const lvalue reference. Note that for this to work `FieldX` should either be `static` or global variable.

```
constexpr char FieldX[] = "my_field_or_option";
constexpr auto& OptY = FieldX;
```

Comment: `OptY` is not an alias for `FieldX`. It is an alias for `const char[19]`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Note that is what OP wants. In particular, they've written *"I'd like to have `OptY` as effectively `constexpr char[]`*. Same thing written in the title of the question.

Comment: No, that's not what OP wants. That's just sloppy wording on their part. Read the question again. OP wants to alias **variables**, and these aliases need to be **constexpr**. A type cannot be constexpr.